# Unit Test is not working

Tags: junit

Can someone please tell me why my Unit Test is not working. I'm very new to Unit testing. It's the query that's not running and I'm not sure why ???

```
public class ContactsServiceTest {

@Autowired
private ContactsService contactsService;

@Test
public void testGetContactsById() {
    Contacts con =  contactsService.getContactsById(59);
    assertTrue(con.getFirstName().equals("Jon"));
}
```

}

This is the error I get;

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.logicalideas.myapp.ContactsServiceTest.testGetContactsById(ContactsServiceTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Your service or contact is null. Don't know which, because you don't tell us which line the NPE is on. I don't understand the question, though; can't you figure out what's null?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's the query that is not executing here (in test method), it's working fine otherwise. I don't understand why not ? Contacts con =  contactsService.getContactsById(59);

Comment: Again--can't you figure out what's null?! If it's the line you say it is, obviously there's no service.

Answer (score 1):

According to your error stacktrace and as long as line 45 is

```
Contacts con =  contactsService.getContactsById(59);
```

then id 59 you are trying to retrieve does not hold any information or there is an issue with the connection.

Unless you post more information of your system it is difficult to figure out what is the exact problem causing this.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NullPointerException

private ContactsService contactsService = new ContactsService();

Comment: That's not particularly good advice when a DI framework is being used, nor does it lend itself to easy testability.